# given a basic neighborhood space, finding an algorithm that will determine the open sets of that space.

Tags: general-topology, algorithms

I would like to figure out how to find open sets of the basic neighborhood space ($\mathcal{B}_X,X$) where $X$ is the space and $\mathcal{B}_X$ is the basic neighborhood on $X$. The second to last paragraph is what I am thinking that might work (without having to go recursive or have a large tree). I am hoping to find/design something efficient to do this.

I first tried to look at this problem from a basic neighborhood point of view. by the definition of basic neighborhood we have:

Let $X$ be a non-empty set, and suppose that for each $x \in X$ there exists a non-empty family of subsets of $X$ denoted $U_x$ that satisfy the following properties:

$1. x \in U \forall U \in U_x$;

$ 2. \text{ if } U \in U_x \text{ and } V \in U_x \text{ then } \exists W \in U_x \text{ such that } W \subset U \cap V$;

$ 3. \text{ if } y \in U \text{ and } U \in U_x \text{ then } \exists V \in U_y \text{ with } V \subset U$

Each $U \in U_x$ is called a $\textit{basic neighborhood}$ of $x$.

The problem is that since most time I am not dealing with singleton sets I have to check whether or not each point in any set follows the above axioms, which of course would have me jumping and recursively testing? each point in a potential basic neighborhood of that point!

Instead, say I try to do this with accumulation/limit points to determined the closed and hence open sets:

Let $X = \{a,b,c\}, \mathcal{B}_X = \{\mathcal{N}_a,\mathcal{N}_b,\mathcal{N}_c\}$ where $\mathcal{N}_a = \{\{a\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},X\},\mathcal{N}_b = \{\{b\},\{a,b\},\{b,c\},X\}$ and $\mathcal{N}_c = \{\{b,c\},X\}$. How would we formulate an algorithm to tell me which sets are open and which are closed? Now I am thinking that we could take the deleted basic neighborhoods i.e. $\mathcal{N}_{-a} = \{\{b\},\{c\},\{b,c\},\mathcal{N}_{-b} = \{\{a\},\{c\},\{a,c\}\}$ and $\mathcal{N}_{-c} = \{\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$. Then perhaps we could go on to finding the accumulation points and find out which sets contain their accumulation points are closed. After finding which sets are closed, (call them $C_i$, $i$ in an indexing set of closed sets $\mathcal{C}$ in the basic neighborhood Space ($\mathcal{B}_X,X$)), then if $\exists O \in \mathcal{B}_X$ such that $ X-O$ ($X$ delete $O$) is closed then $O$ is open.

However according to Wikipedia - the accumulation point (limit point):

Let S be a subset of a topological space X. A point x in X is a limit point of S if every neighbourhood of x contains at least one point of S different from x itself.

Thus we have the issue of the neighborhood of x and having to find if x is contained in an open set in the neighborhood. We are thus back to the problem of determining whether the set is open in the first place. The second to last paragraph notes what I hope is a possibility without recursion or a large amount of sorting!

Can I bypass all of this limit point talk and just see if $(\mathcal{B}_X,X)$ is a topology as according to wikipedia the sets of a topology are $\textbf{open}$. Hence I wouldn't have to create some sort of recursive algorithm to check the neighborhoods of each point $b \in U_a \in \mathcal{N}_a$ and see if all $U_b \in \mathcal{N}_b$ follow the definition of a neighborhood.  -- ?

In the end I am looking for an efficient algorithm to determine the open sets of a space $X$ given a basic neighborhood space $(\mathcal{B}_X,X)$ (otherwise the set of all possible subsets of $X$ would be both open and closed).

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: I doubt that axiom 3. is correct. To define a topology by neighbourhood systems usually we demand: for all $x$ and all $U \in \mathcal{U}_x$, there exists a $V \in \mathcal{U_x}$ such that $\forall y \in V: U \in \mathcal{U}_y$. This corresponds to the idea that every neighbourhood of a point should contain an open neighbourhood of that point. What is a reference for your version?

Comment: On second thought, it seems like you are not axiomatising neighbourhoods in general, but (subfamilies of) open neighbourhoods. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using some axiomatisation of open basic neighbourhoods. A set $O \subset X$ is open iff for every $x \in O$ there exists some $U \in \mathcal{U}_x$ such that $U_x \subset O$. This is equivalent to: all open subsets are unions from $\cup_{x \in X} \mathcal{U}_x$.

So a simple way to get all open sets: take all unions from $\mathcal{B} = \cup_{x \in X} \mathcal{U}_x$. This includes the empty union, i.e. the union of no sets from $\mathcal{B}$, which equals $\emptyset$, and all unions of *one* element from $\mathcal{B}$, which are just all the individual members of $\mathcal{B}$, and so on. Assuming your are working in finite sets and all $\mathcal{U}_x$ are completely known, this gives all open sets pretty easily. On could optimise a bit to not try too many unions, but this is a matter of implementation.

As to your example above: this doesn't satisfy your third axiom, as $c \in \{a,c\} \in \mathcal{N}_a$, but no member of $\mathcal{N}_c$ is a subset of it.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that I can not just take some set of subsets of a space $X$ and divide them in to basic basic neighborhoods as I would have to have each of the axioms fulfilled so as to have a "Basic Neighborhood System". So am I correct in saying that only then can I start talking of "Basic Neighborhoods" i.e. as not all of the axioms are satisfied, I don't have a basic neighborhood system which means dividing the subsets in to those of basic neighborhoods of a point doesn't make any sense as it is NECESSARY to have all 3 axioms fulfilled so as to talk about basic neighborhoods of each point?

Comment: Yes, you need all three if you want this to be an axiomisation of the notion of basic open neighbourhoods of a topological space. Only (1),(2) are needed to show we get *a* topology (taking all unions), but (3) is needed to see that we the $\mathcal{U}_x$ are exactly a local open base for that same topology.